# Is it possible to declare several 'for' loop terminations in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I know the sintax in the `for` loop in Java. Normally looks something like

```
for(initialization; termination; increment){
    ...
}
//Example
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    ...
}
```

And I also know already that we can declare several initializations and increments, such as

```
//Example
int i,j;
//  ini1,  ini2 ;  term ;  inc1,  inc2
for(i=0,   j=100;  i<100;  i++,   j--){
    ...
}
```

My very clear question is: Is it possible to have more than one termination as well? something may be like

```
//Example
int i,j;
//  ini1,   ini2 ;   term1,   term2;   inc1,  inc2
for(i=0,    j=100;   i<100,   j>34;    i++,   j--){
    ...
}
```

Because I'm trying it and it's giving me an error, and I'd rather not to use too many `if` sentences inside the loop to determine wether to continue or break.

Is it sintax, or it's just not pssible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply any `boolean` condition, which may include logical boolean operators such as `!`, `&&`, and/or `||`:

```
for(i=0,    j=100;  i<100 && j>34;    i++,   j--){
```

They can be as simple or complex as you'd like, as long as it evaluates to a `boolean`.

Comment: All of the answers are basically the same, quite helpful, but you were the first who pointed out I can use any boolean operator as long as gives as result a boolean. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Example
int i,j;
//  ini1,   ini2 ;   term1,   term2;   inc1,  inc2
for(i=0,    j=100;   i<100 &&  j>34;    i++,   j--){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the logical operators `||` and `&&` to indicate your stopping conditions:

```
for(i=0, j=100; i < 100 || j > 34; i++, j--)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to stop when `i<100` *AND* `j>34`. In java, an AND is writen with &&. So, your loop can be:

```
int i,j;
for(i=0,    j=100;   i<100 &&   j>34;    i++,   j--){
    ...
}
```

Read, at least, [this](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/45.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one... condition in `for` loop, but this condition can be build from few others, using logical operators like `&&` which means "AND", `||` which means "OR"?

If you want to end loop if **all** conditions `i<100`, `j>34` are fulfilled then you should use logical AND operator `i<100 && j>34`.
If you want to end loop if **at least one** of conditions `i<100`, `j>34` is fulfilled then you should use logical OR operator `i<100 || j>34`.

Answer (score 1):

you can give as many conditions,combined by Logical AND/OR,as you wish given that your expression evaluate to a boolean true/false value.

As per Java Language specification,Java SE 7 Edition:

*"The basic for statement executes some initialization code, then executes an
Expression, a Statement, and some update code repeatedly until the value of the
Expression is false.*

*BasicForStatement:
for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement"*

*...The Expression must have type boolean or Boolean,*"